# Complex array normalization

Tags: python, complex-numbers

I have a list of complex values that displays the complex amplitudes for a wave function. Each value, real and imaginary, is randomly generated in `[-1,1)`. I need to normalize this list in such a way that the sum of the squares of all complex numbers is `(1+0j)`.
My code:

```
import numpy as np
from random import *
num_qubits = 4

state = np.zeros((2**num_qubits), dtype=np.complex64)
for i in range(2**num_qubits):
  state[i] = complex(uniform(-1,1),uniform(-1,1))

state = state / np.sqrt(np.sum(state**2))
print(state)
a = 0
for i in range(len(state)):
  a += state[i]**2
print(a) ### should be (1+0j)
```

My code does not give the desired result: the real and imaginary parts of a tend to 1 and 0, respectively, but do not reach them.

Sample output:

```
[-0.3697332 -0.0641938j  -0.88676226+0.4232571j   0.41884637+0.05547267j
  0.29857516-0.10600297j -0.4333445 -0.13364498j  0.4524058 +0.22443457j
  0.22225586+0.57373726j -0.6371718 -0.9841412j   0.03181012+0.85295266j
 -0.39558408-0.12434599j  0.87118745-0.19153355j  1.0328128 -0.1446039j
 -0.52917427+0.76342076j  0.52730054+0.15673561j -0.07593771-0.6453003j
  0.09273791-0.45075825j]
(1.0000003097685062-9.316019511373952e-08j)
```

I need to somehow transform the array `state` after it is filled with random complex values so that the value `a` (the sum of the squares of the elements  `state[i]`) takes on the value `(1+0j)`

Comment: Do you understand complex numbers? What is `1j**2`? Hint it's not `1`. Just divide your array by its `np.linalg.norm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works. It is just that you only have equality to machine precision. For example, I just ran your code changing to `np.complex128` and the result for `a` was
`(0.9999999999999999-1.734723475976807e-16j)`

Comment: I know, but is there a way to round the result so that it is exactly (1+0j) for a?

Comment: You don't need to. Any calculation you do with the array will be correct because you have the precision already. Rounding the individual values in the array will just make things worse. You could round the actual value for `a` with `a_round = round(a.real)+round(a.imag)*1j`